# neo4j - how to snapshot everything in a label

Tags: neo4j

Im using **neo4j** to store information about maps and sensors. Every time the map or sensor layout changes I need to keep a copy. I can imagine querying and manually creating said copy but I'm wondering if it's possible to build a neo4j type query that would do this for me.

So far all I've come up with is a way to replicate the nodes in a given label:

```
match ( a:some_label { some_params }) with a create ( b:some_label ) set b=a,b.other_id=value;
```

This would allow me to put *version* and *time stamp* info on a given snap shot.

What it doesn't do is copy the edge information. Suggestions? Maybe a second (similar) query?

Comment: Why don't you `match`/`create` the relationships as well?

Comment: i would - the syntax is escaping me though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are essentially trying to maintain a history of the state of a node and the state of its incoming relationship. One way to do this is to chain the nodes in reverse chronological order.

For example, suppose the nodes in the chain are labeled `Some_label` and the relationships are of type `SOME_TYPE`. The head node of the chain is always the current (most recent) node. Unless a `Some_label` node is chronologically the earliest node in the chain, it will have a `SOME_TYPE` relationship to the previous version of the node.

Here is how you'd insert a new relationship and node (with some properties) at the head of the chain. (Just to set up this example, I assume that the first node in the chain is linked to by some node labeled `HeadRef`).

```
MATCH (x:HeadRef)-[r1:SOME_TYPE]->(a1:Some_label)
CREATE (x)-[r2:SOME_TYPE {x: "ghi"}]->(a2:Some_label {a:123, b: true})-[r:SOME_TYPE]->(a1)
SET r=r1
WITH r1
DELETE r1
```

Note that this approach is also much more performant than maintaining your own `other_id` property to link nodes together. You should always use relationships instead -- that is the graph DB way.

Comment: I presently have blocks of nodes+edges grouped by labels. Are you proposing to link each node to its historical predecessor and also to the other new nodes as each snapshot is made?

Comment: Yes. And this way, you don't need a different  label for each group.