# localhost:7474/graphaware/changefeed/CFM gives 404

Tags: neo4j, graphaware

i am trying to track latest changes in neo4j in **Server Mode**

so i followed this link https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-changefeed

as i see some extra node are added and here are changes about my db

[image]

but http://localhost:7474/graphaware/changefeed/CFM gives me 404

i am using **neo4j 2.2.2**

and my neo4j.properties

```
com.graphaware.runtime.enabled=true
com.graphaware.module.CFM.1=com.graphaware.module.changefeed.ChangeFeedModuleBootstrapper

com.graphaware.module.CFM.maxChanges=100

com.graphaware.module.CFM.pruneDelay=10000

com.graphaware.module.CFM.pruneWhenExceeded=10

com.graphaware.module.CFM.node=!hasLabel('NotIncluded')

com.graphaware.module.CFM.relationship=!isType('NOT_INCLUDED')
```

plugins i added

```
graphaware-server-community-all-2.2.2.31.jar
graphaware-changefeed-2.2.2.31.7.jar
```

Comment: Which version of Neo4j? Please also share the module config in neo4j.properties

Comment: Any exceptions in console.log or neo4j*.log? Is authentication enabled/disabled for the neo4j server?

Comment: @Luanne authentication is disabled and in console i am getting "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:7474/graphaware/changefeed/"

Comment: Hmm strange. In console.log can you check if graphaware and the changefeed are mounted? You should see stuff like Mounting GraphAware Framework under /graphaware and  Mapped "{[/changefeed/{moduleId}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.Collection<com.graphaware.module.changefeed.domain.ChangeSet>

Comment: @Luanne i think i misunderstanding the console.log i was checking browser console, where i get this console.log?? sorry i am begginer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81108/discussion-between-luanne-and-govind-singh-nagarkoti).

Comment: Did you install Neo4j from the installer or zip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GraphAware framework and modules will work on Windows only if you've installed Neo4j from the zip and ***not*** the installer.